# Can't port forward on my static public IP with my TD-W9980 router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I believe I have set up my port forwarding correctly.
[image: Router setup page.]

TPG (my internet provider) said port forwarding is possible with them and they don't block any ports.

Multiple port checkers state the port is false, I've read lots of port forwarding port troubleshooting tips to no avail.

Is there something I'm over looking?

I have exceptions in my Windows firewall and I have a static IP address for my PC.

Comment: What device and application are you trying to port forward to? Is the firewall on this device set to allow traffic on the port?

Comment: What application are you trying to forward to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the "Virtual Server" settings ([see manual page 79](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/document/TD-W9980_1.0_User_Guide_1910010923.pdf)). Port triggering is used for (copy from page 82):

> Once the modem router is configured, the operation is as follows:
>
> 1. A local host makes an outgoing connection to an external host using a destination port number defined in the Trigger Port field.
> 2. The modem router records this connection, opens the incoming port or ports associated with this entry in the Port Triggering table, and
>    associates them with the local host.
> 3. When necessary, the external host will be able to connect to the local host using one of the ports defined in the Incoming Ports field.

It is not used for incoming connections which are triggered from outside!

Of course, to have it working you have to have an application listening on that port not only having the firewall on Windows allowing the port.

After you set up the "Virtual Server" a port scanner should show you the port is open (even without having a running application listening) - it will try to port forward it. I use [ShieldsUp](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) for testing.

Comment: @hazzahazzam I think you do need to have the application running otherwise the port checker won't find anything at that port (except possibly a PC that rejects its connection) but I'm not sure.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to have fixed your issue

Comment: hazzahazzam - glad you fixed it and @LJD200 - you are correct, I tested it with my router with port 80 and forgot I have skype running - which uses port 80 if it is free (and I don't have any http server running) :)