# Unable to enable port forwarding on linksys router

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding, bridge-router

I have a linksys BEFSR81 V3 router which I use along with an apple airport extreme. The apple airport is setup in bridged mode as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wskhi.png). On my actual router page, I have UPnP enabled as [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfhAR.png). I also have my port forwarded like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH5fD.png). So, to me it seems as though everything should be working fine. However, when I go to http://www.canyouseeme.org/, I get [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzvUB.png) I would very much appreciate any help as this has been happening for a while and I have been unable to fix it even after extensive research.

> Update: I am using uTorrent in order to test my port forwarding configuration. I have uTorrent configured to run on the port I am attempting to forward as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Which application do you have which has this port open?

Comment: @RonMaupin I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You have set up port triggering instead of port forward on your router. The former is triggered from inside. So if you have set up your torrent app to use 1111 port go to the section "Port Triggering" on your router. Different router same problem here [Can't port forward on my static public IP with my TD-W9980 router](https://superuser.com/questions/1043276/cant-port-forward-on-my-static-public-ip-with-my-td-w9980-router/1043391#1043391)

Comment: In my router, it gives the options for "triggered range" and "forwarded range". What do I select for these?

Comment: Ah, sorry, [User Guide](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/BEFSR81_V31_UG_NC-WEB.pdf) on page 9, you are on the correct part, your settings should be okay, please check your local firewall on the computer if it allows port 1111 for incoming and you have to have the torrent app running and listening (this you can check in terminal with `netstat -an | grep 1111`